# Importing Python class from sibling directory

Tags: python, import, module, package, relative-import

My Directory structure in `/VM/repo/project` is:

```
__init__.py

scripts/
      getSomething.py
      __init__.py

classes/
      project.py
      db.py
      __init__.py
```

#### getSomething.py

```
from ..classes import project
from ..classes import db
```

#### project.py

```
class PROJECT:
def __init__(self):
    stuff
```

#### db.py

```
class DB:
def __init__(self):
    stuff
```

When I try to run

```sh
python getSomething.py
```

I get the error

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "scripts/getSomething.py", line 4, in < module >
>   from ..classes import project
>   ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As stated in the error, you're running `getSomething` as a main module.  But you can't do package relative imports when you aren't in a package.  The main module is never in a package.  So, if you were to import `getSomething` as part of a package...:

```
# /VM/repo/main.py
from project.scripts import getSomething
```

Then you would not have the import errors.

---

Perhaps it is helpful to have a quick discussion on python modules and packages.  In general, a file that contains python source code and has the `.py` extension is a module.  Typically that module's name is the name of the file (sans extension), but if you run it directly, that module's name is `'__main__'`.  So far, this is all well known and documented.  To import a module you just do `import module` or `import package.module` and so on.  This last import statement refers to something else (a "package") which we'll talk about now...

Packages are directories that you can import.  Many directories can't be imported (e.g. maybe they have no python source files -- modules -- in them).  So to resolve this ambiguity, there is also the requirement that the directory has an `__init__.py` file.  When you import a directory on your filesystem, python actually imports the `__init__.py` module and creates the associated package from the things in `__init__.py` (if there are any).

Putting all of this together shows why executing a file inside a directory that has an `__init__.py` is not enough for python to consider the module to be part of a package.  First, the name of the module is `__main__`, not `package.filename_sans_extension`.  Second, the creation of a package depends not just on the filesystem structure, but on whether the directory (and therefore `__init__.py` was actually imported).

You might be asking yourself "Why did they design it this way?"  Indeed, I've asked myself that same question on occasion.  I think that the reason is because the language designers want certain guarantees to be in place for a package.  A package should be a unit of things which are designed to work together for a specific purpose.  It shouldn't be a silo of scripts that by virtue of a few haphazard `__init__.py` files gain the ability to walk around the filesystem to find the other modules that they need.  If something is designed to be run as a main module, then it probably shouldn't be part of the package.  Rather it should be a separate module that imports the package and relies on it.

Comment: Okay, so a couple things:

I was under the impression that adding `__init__.py` to each directory essentially defines those directories as a package? I might have a fundamental misunderstanding of packages here. Why is that the main module is never in a package? 

Secondly: my goal is to run the scripts on a cron. Is there no way to import the classes into the scripts directly? Creating another file `main.py` one more layer up seems needlessly convoluted to me.

Comment: @ShaneOH -- I've tried (as best I can) to edit my answer to hopefully clear up any ambiguity... I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, the original answer and edit are both extremely helpful. So I have one final question: What if I want to keep this directory structure and run the scripts directly, as main modules? So okay, they don't need to be part of the package. How do I import the /classes modules into a main module in a sibling folder? And do I then remove `__init__.py` from /scripts and from /project?

Comment: You can add `path/to/project` to your `PYTHONPATH`.  Then your scripts should be able to `import project.classes.xyz` from wherever they are in the filesystem....

Comment: Got it. Unfortunate that this all seems so non-intuitive, but I can understand the merits that you describe. Thanks again!